# Buffer does not intersect or contain the point used for the center of the buffer when creating the buffer

Tags: buffer, shapely, pyproj

I made the buffer below (see code).  I then tried to see if the buffer contains or intersects the center of the buffer, but False is returned.  Why?

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

import pyproj

srcProj = pyproj.Proj(init="epsg:5070")
dstProj = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:32612')

pt = (-94.6091, 39.1063)

x, y = pyproj.transform(srcProj, dstProj, pt[0], pt[1])

pt = Point(x,y)

buf = pt.buffer(100)

buffer_points = zip(buf.exterior.coords.xy[0], 
buf.exterior.coords.xy[1])

proj_buffer_points = []

for point in buffer_points:
    x = point[0]
    y = point[1]
    x, y = pyproj.transform(dstProj, srcProj, x, y)
    proj_buffer_points.append((x, y))

print Polygon(proj_buffer_points).intersects(pt)
print Polygon(proj_buffer_points).contains(pt)

False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues in your code. Main of them is this:

```
srcProj = pyproj.Proj(init="epsg:5070")
dstProj = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:32612')
```

It must be:

```
srcProj = pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:4326')
dstProj = pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:5070')
```

Another one is that you chose wrong point (you don't need to reproject back as it was pointed out by @mgc).

Complete fixed code is:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

import pyproj

srcProj = pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:4326')
dstProj = pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:5070')

pt1 = (-94.6091, 39.1063)

x, y = pyproj.transform(srcProj, dstProj, pt1[0], pt1[1])

pt = Point(x,y)

buffer = pt.buffer(1000)

buffer_points =  zip(buffer.exterior.coords.xy[0], buffer.exterior.coords.xy[1])

proj_buffer_points = []

for point in buffer_points:
    x = point[0]
    y = point[1]
    x, y = pyproj.transform(dstProj, srcProj, x, y)
    proj_buffer_points.append((x, y))

print Polygon(proj_buffer_points)
print Polygon(proj_buffer_points).intersects(Point(pt1))
print Polygon(proj_buffer_points).contains(Point(pt1))
```

After running it at console, it's printed out:

```
True
True
```

as it is expected.

With the printed polygon geometry (format WKT) and the help of QuickWKT plugin of QGIS, it can be observed that your buffer and your point are between Kansas and Missouri USA states. I hope that it helps.

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. By the way,  if this is the expected  anwer, could you mark as accepted? Thanks.

Comment: Why does it have to be 
srcProj = pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:4326')
dstProj = pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:5070') and not

srcProj = pyproj.Proj(init="EPSG:5070")
dstProj = pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:32612')

I'm a bit confused.  srcProj refers to source projection and dstProj refers to destination projections, right?  Why is 5070 the source and 32612 the destination?  Am I interpreting those variables correctly?  Is there any tutorial for beginners about what all this stuff means and how to find the projection for USA lat/long that I need to get proper Haversine distances between US coordinates?

Comment: Why does it have to be srcProj = pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:4326') dstProj = pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:5070') and not srcProj = pyproj.Proj(init="EPSG:5070") dstProj = pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:32612') I'm a bit confused. srcProj refers to source projection and dstProj refers to destination projections, right? Why is 5070 the source and 32612 the destination? Am I interpreting those variables correctly? Is there any tutorial for beginners about what all this stuff means and how to find the projection for USA lat/long that I need to get proper Haversine distances between US coordinates?

Comment: I'm busy now. I'll answer your comment questions later.

Comment: One previous question. It's point (-94.6091, 39.1063) situated  between Kansas and Missouri USA states? EPSG code is 4326?

Comment: Yes, it is in the Kansas and Missouri area.  EPSG code is 4326?  I have no idea.  I want to use a code which is valid for all points in the continental US.

Comment: If your point is at the middle of following image (red mark) then it is in EPSG:4326: https://postimg.org/image/9os31kdux/ . Please, confirm that.

Comment: What if my point is anywhere within the continental US?

Comment: Never mind. You can use EPSG:5070 and 4326 as in the code. EPSG 5070 is valid for contiguous lower 48 states (check it out here: http://prj2epsg.org/epsg/5070).

Comment: Thanks.  What is EPSG:4326 in the sourceProj?  What is that for?  Can I use it for any point in the contiguous lower 48 states?

Comment: EPSG:4326 is referred to Coordinate Reference System `+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs` and it can be used for any point in the contiguous lower 48 states if you have these coordinates.

Comment: Why is that used for srcProj, and what is srcProj?  Why is 5070 used for dstProj, and what is dstProj?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just forgot to reproject back the point you are testing, so when you are doing `Polygon(proj_buffer_points).intersects(pt)` your polygon is back in "epsg:5070" projection but you point is still in 'epsg:32612' projection.

Change back the coordinates of your point `pt` to "epsg:5070" projection and the predicate will be `True` for intersects and contains :

```
...
pt = Point(pyproj.transform(dstProj, srcProj, pt.coords.xy[0][0], pt.coords.xy[1][0]))
# Or just retype it by hand:
# pt = Point(-94.6091, 39.1063)
print Polygon(proj_buffer_points).intersects(pt) # True
print Polygon(proj_buffer_points).contains(pt) # True
```